# Declare a local module in flowtype

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'd like to create a `testlib.js.flow` for local module `testlib.js`, first the code for `testlib.js`:

```
exports.hello_lib = function (str,  num ) {}
```

then here is a code uses `testlib.js` in the same folder:

```
const testlib = require('./testlib')
testlib.hello_lib('this is a string', 'test')
```

now the code for `testlib.js.flow`:

```
declare module 'testlib' {
  declare function hello_lib (str : string, num : number) : any;  
}
```

when flow, it does not check, any idea what's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `testlib.js.flow` in the same directory as `testlib.js`? If so, I think you can just make the file `declare export function hello_lib (str : string, num : number) : any;`.

Comment: This shouldn't type-check. The second argument to `hello_lib` is a number but you are passing a string 'test'.